# Node JS: отправка почты

Tags: node.js

Добрый день.

Я хочу реализовать простую отправку **почты** на Node JS.
Гугл подсказывает **nodemailer**, там просто и понятно, но походу он заточен под Gmail-почту, других примеров я не нашел.

Есть ли возможность на Node JS написать что-то подобное new SmtpCLient.Send(message) как в C# ?

Спасибо

**UPD:**

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail', // !!!!!
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass:  'password'
    },
    logger: bunyan.createLogger({
        name: 'nodemailer'
    }),
```

Comment: С чего вдруг вывод, что "походу он заточен по Gmail-почту*? Ничего подобного.

Comment: по UPD: и? 1) если можно указать `service: 'gmail'`, то, очевидно, можно указать и что-то другое. 2) если почитать документацию, то окажется, что параметр `service` вообще необязательный, и введен для удобства, чтобы не надо было указывать вручную адреса и порты популярных почтовых служб.

Answer (score 2):

Например можно попробовать **[emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs)** или на Гите
https://github.com/eleith/emailjs

Answer (score 1):

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer'); // отлично работает и с Яндекс
```

...

```
const output = `
<p>You have a new contact request</p>
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>  
  <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
  <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
  <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p>
<h3>Headers</h3>
<ul>  
  <li>cookie: ${req.headers.cookie}</li>
  <li>user-agent: ${req.headers["user-agent"]}</li>
  <li>referer: ${req.headers["referer"]}</li>
  <li>IP: ${req.ip}</li>
</ul>
  `;

  let smtpTransport;
  try {
    smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: 'smtp.yandex.ru',
      port: 465,
      secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports 587
      auth: {
        user: "mymail@yandex.ru",
        pass: "mypass"
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return console.log('Error: ' + e.name + ":" + e.message);
  }

  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'mymail@yandex.ru', // sender address
    to: 'anotheruser@romb.cloud, myuser@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Обращение с сайта baedeker.club', // Subject line
    text: 'Обращение с сайта baedeker.club', // plain text body
    html: output // html body
  };

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      // return console.log(error);
      return console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    }
res.render('feed-ok', {msg: 'В ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся и ответим на все вопросы'});
res.redirect('http://baedeker.club')
```

})

...