# Отправка писем с телеграм бота ( Telegraph.js можно и через чистую Node.js( без фреймворков ) )

Tags: node.js, api, telegram, email

у меня появилась задача, хочу узнать возможно ли отправить письма пользователям через телеграм бот, к примеру есть массив юзеров и их почта

(сейчас бот написан с помощью telegraph.js)
но если есть способ решения на чистой ноде, смогу переработать

```
users = ['Eduard', 'Oleg', 'Genry'];
usersEmails= ['123@gmail.com', '1234@gmail.com', '12345@gmail.com']
```

юзеры пишут свои имена и почту, бот их пушит в массивы,  в целом задача либо отправить после этого письмо на почту, либо написать в личку человеку, возможно есть подсказки по данной теме, буду благодарен. Предполагаю, что перед тем, как рассылать будет сформирован объект с пользователями

```
users = {

usersInfo: 
[
        { name: "Eduard", email: "123@gmail.com"},
        { name: "Oleg", email: "1234@gmail.com"},
        { name: "Genry", email: "12345@gmail.com"}
    ]
}
```

после чего перебором уже делать отправку, проверять на Имя и узнавать кому отправляем, чтобы указать в письме/смс
возможно как решение пушить в MongoDB, и что то делать дальше с ними, вот тут нуждаюсь в подсказке так же

Comment: Здесь варианты модулей для отправки email из nodejs https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623166/node-js-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B  "Либо написать в личку человеку" если имеется в виду в телеграм, то по chatId пользователя...

Comment: спасибо большое, буду пробовать )

Comment: nodemailer помог,спасибо большое, вопрос закрыт )

Comment: Отлично! На здоровье!)